# PhpStorm. Изменение цвета заголовка файлов (tabs color)

Tags: ide, phpstorm, php

Всем привет) Вопрос прост, но решения найти не смог.

Сначала изображение:
[image]
Теперь, сам вопрос: **Как изменить цвет текста в заголовках файлов, IDE PhpStorm?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Editor - Colors & Fonts - File Status`

Делаете новую схему (через Save As...) и меняете `Foreground` у различных типов файлов на нужный цвет.

Comment: Вот спасибо, Рома )